# Loading templates in Freemarker templates without setting Directory or Class for template loading

Tags: java, freemarker

Is there any way of loading the Freemarker templates directly without having need to first load the `Directory`  from which templates will be loaded or setting the `Class` relative to which templates will be loaded.

i.e Is there any way so that i can load a template like

```
Template template = getTemplate("PathToTemplate/myTemplate.ftl");
```

I need this, because user specifies the complete path to `ftl` files. So,first i have to separate directory name and file name, then i am doing

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

int indexOfLast = templatePath.lastIndexOf("\\");
String dir = templatePath;
String fileName="";
if(indexOfLast>=0){
        dir = templatePath.substring(0,indexOfLast);
        fileName=  templatePath.substring(indexOfLast+1,templatePath.length());
}
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(dir));
Template template = cfg.getTemplate(fileName);
```

I do not want to do all this.

Comment: What do you mean by `loading the Freemarker templates directly` - where should be your `PathToTemplate` ? Is it relative to something? Or absolute?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Its on a connected network. `Loading templates directly` means i do not want two steps. First, set directory or path for loading the templates, then `config.getTemplate('templateFile.ftl')` to get the template. Instead `something.getTemplate('dir path/templateFile.ftl')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates can be created by directly calling a `Template` constructor, to which you pass a `String` or `Reader` as argument. Then of course you get that `Reader` or `String` from wherever you want. This approach has two disadvantages though:

- Other templates won't be able to `#import` or `#include` those templates, as FreeMarker doesn't know how to load them (only you do)
- Caching those templates (if that's needed anyway) is up to you

If the above two is a problem for you, then see Seelenvirtuose's answer: create a `TemplateLoader` that interprets the template names as full paths.

As of your example code, know that the `Configuration` instance will clear its template cache every time you replace the `TemplateLoader`. Also note that it's not thread-safe to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `getTemplate` method is heavily overloaded. As per the documentation the method [`getTemplate(String, Locale, String, boolean)`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#getTemplate%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) will eventually be called regardless which `getTemplate` method you called.

This method's documentation expresses the following:

> The exact syntax of the name is interpreted by the underlying TemplateLoader, but the cache makes some assumptions. First, the name is expected to be a hierarchical path, with path components separated by a slash character (not with backslash!). The path (the name) given here must not begin with slash; it's always interpreted relative to the "template root directory".

There are two notable things:

1. The `name` parameter is already handling a hierarchical path, but must not begin with a slash. So maybe you could set the configuration's directory *once* to the root of your disk and then simply provide the full path (but without the leading slash).
2. The documentation explains something about a [`TemplateLoader`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/TemplateLoader.html). So you can simply write an implementation of that interface for loading the template. In that implementation you have full hands on the provided *name*.